# How to automate gmail sign in for googleSignIn POD using XCUITest

Tags: ios, google-signin, xcuitest

I have integrated googleSignIn POD and end user able to sign in. For UI automation purpose, I want to automate the sign in process.

Is it possible to sign in Gmail account using XCUITest?
Sample scripts will be more helpful.

Comment: Have you attempted to use the Xcode recorder to try and get a baseline of whether this is possible?

Comment: Yes, absolutely possible. What have you tried?

Comment: @BrandonStillitano Yes tried, but not working. 
Gmail login process is shows alert "“App” Wants to Use “google.com” to Sign In""-> added email id -> password -> success
When I record it, for alter it gives code as : "app.alerts["“SecureMailClient” Wants to Use “google.com” to Sign In"].scrollViews.otherElements.buttons["Continue"].tap()"
But when I re-run it, it fails for alter "Continue" button tap. 

Xcode error as:
Failed to get matching snapshot: No matches found for Descendants matching type Alert from input {(
    Application, pid: 68037, label: 'App'
)}

Comment: @MikeCollins : I have tried following things:
1. Try to get the "Continue" alert button of Gmail login. But not found button/alert in hierarchy. Even "po app.alerts.count" is 0 when gmail alert is shown.
2. Tried using recording option. Able to record it, but when re-run it fails.

Could you please let us know how you are able to run it?

Comment: Could this be a timing issue? Have you tried an artificial `sleep()` prior to the tap?

Comment: Yes, I have checked using sleep as well i.e. make sure when tap is going to execute Gmail alert is on screen. Still it is not working

Answer (score 0):

The alert asking you if you want to allow the app to use google.com, is not a traditional alert. You need to access it via springboard like so:

```
let springboardApp = XCUIApplication(bundleIdentifier: "com.apple.springboard")
springboardApp.alerts.buttons["Continue"].tap()
```